# Use Linux to backup a MSWindows network?

Tags: windows, linux, networking, backup

Is it possible to use a Linux machine to backup everything on a Windows network?

I would like to backup MS databases and also drives, so if a database record needs restoring, it can be done easily, and if a drive gets corrupted, it can be re-imaged easily.

Comment: How are you operating the network? Linux can access NFS and NTFS by default, and Samba can handle different types of workgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into setting up bacula server on your linux box. Bacula is an open source project with a very good win gui client and an excellent backend. I'm not going to post any configurations here because they vary depending on needs.